# How to download a video from YouTube in Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)

Tags: video

How can I download a video from the YouTube URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TA1MSeWA6Wk?

Comment: flashgot or downloadhelper addons in firefox

Answer (score 3):

You can use `smtube`  to download video from YouTube. It is  a stand-alone graphical application which allows one to search and download YouTube videos.

[image]

Although it is part of the SMPlayer project, it can be used with any multimedia player
such as MPlayer, MPlayer2, VLC, Totem or Gnome-MPlayer.

Use `sudo apt-get install smtube smplayer` to install SMPlayer YouTube Browser and SMPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot add comments so I'm leaving this link here:

http://www.marksanborn.net/howto/using-wget-to-download-youtube-videos/

If this proves worth to you, I'll write out what it says in the link, in case the link dies.

Comment: thanks for your quick response,but still i'm not able to download.... Please help me out.!!!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can install youtube-dl and use it to download YouTube videos.

```
 sudo apt-get install youtube-dl

 youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TA1MSeWA6Wk
```

Also, go through the man pages of youtube-dl to set various options like video format and video quality.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can't anymore. Those don't even work anymore; I tried them. YouTube changed things where it will be next to impossible to download without an approved browser with either a Flash player or HTML5 player, with your login cookies.

Be grateful they haven't started using IPCP such as Photobucket, which will block *all* Linux distributions except Android, but it's coming. Sigh. This is similar to HDCP where the video is encrypted and only an approved device (yes, it's Microsoft based) can display it, despite the fact, YouTube does not own any copyright and violates basic free use laws. In other words, the downloaded video will appear corrupted once downloaded. There might be "decryptors" in the future, but unlike DVD and Blu-ray players, new keys can be created and removed often enough to make it difficult to keep up.

Video download helper and other applications might still work with older videos on the server, but slowly scripts will be added to all videos in the database. Most videos cannot be downloaded at all from YouTube.