# YouTube video on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: youtube

I wanted to download a YouTube video on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. How do I proceed?

Here is the link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TA1MSeWA6Wk

Comment: You have already asked this question here.http://askubuntu.com/q/514625/146791.

Comment: You should check your browser plugins / extensions page

Answer (score 1):

1. Install smtube (included in standard repositories):

   [08:15:55][mgodby@mg-ws1 ~]$ sudo apt-get -y install smtube
2. Open smtube by pressing 'Super' key and searching for 'smtube' or 'smplayer'. The application is listed by default as "SMPlayer YouTube Browser."
3. Use search bar at bottom to search for a video.
4. Right click the video you wish to save and select option "Record Video". The video will now be downloaded. Open the file now to enjoy anytime!

Hope this has been helpful.

MG

Comment: I found your suggestion really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the "downloadhelper" add-on for Firefox which does a great job of downloading from YouTube and other sites.